# jQuery SignalR client .off() function only removes last registered callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

I'm using SignalR in my application to allow my ASP.NET Server application to push data to my Angular SPA web clients. 
In the web application i've included the jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js file. I do not use the auto generated proxy on http(s)://serverurl/signalr/hubs.

The webapplication has multiple reusable widgets (directives), each with their own isolated scope. Multiple instances of the same widget/directive need to register a callback which can be executed by the server's SignalR Hub so i have a function like this:

```
 var on = function (eventName, callback) {
            proxy.on(eventName, callback);
          };
```

This function is in a seperate service which also has the connection and proxy object, and until now everything is working fine...

From a angular controller,responsible for a widget instance, the above function gets called like this:

```
var callback = function (){
     console.log('Callback fired on controller with Id' + $scope.id)
}

proxyHub.on('myEvent',callback);
```

The controllers are in isolated scope, so the var callback is a different object for each controller.

I am able to register multiple callbacks for the same event from different controllers, and everything is still working as expected.

Now i need to unregister a callback from a controller instance, so i have the following method in my separate service:

```
 var off = function(eventName,callback) {
            proxy.off(eventName,callback);
        };
```

Which gets called from a specific controller instance like this:

```
//callback is exactly the same variable as used in the .on function for this controller   
hubProxy.off('myevent',callback);
```

Here comes the trouble: Only the last registered callback is removed from the event. All other registered callbacks still getting invoked. If i try to call the .off function again, nothing happens, and i am not able to unregister the other callbacks.

The main question is: How can i unregister a specific callback from an event???

Answer (score 7):

From the [hubs source code](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.hubs.js) it seems like it's not possible to unsubscribe multiple duplicate callbacks from a single event.

This is `on` function from the source code:

```
on: function (eventName, callback) {
        /// <summary>Wires up a callback to be invoked when a invocation request is received from the server hub.</summary>
        /// <param name="eventName" type="String">The name of the hub event to register the callback for.</param>
        /// <param name="callback" type="Function">The callback to be invoked.</param>
        var that = this,
            callbackMap = that._.callbackMap;

        // Normalize the event name to lowercase
        eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();

        // If there is not an event registered for this callback yet we want to create its event space in the callback map.
        if (!callbackMap[eventName]) {
            callbackMap[eventName] = {};
        }

        // Map the callback to our encompassed function
        callbackMap[eventName][callback] = function (e, data) {
            callback.apply(that, data);
        };

        $(that).bind(makeEventName(eventName), callbackMap[eventName][callback]);

        return that;
    },
```

as you can see, the "event:callback" pair is saved to `callbackMap` and bound to hub. If you call it multiple times, the `callbackMap` will be overwritten with the same value, but the callback will be bound multiple times.

In the `off` function:

```
off: function (eventName, callback) {
        /// <summary>Removes the callback invocation request from the server hub for the given event name.</summary>
        /// <param name="eventName" type="String">The name of the hub event to unregister the callback for.</param>
        /// <param name="callback" type="Function">The callback to be invoked.</param>
        var that = this,
            callbackMap = that._.callbackMap,
            callbackSpace;

        // Normalize the event name to lowercase
        eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();

        callbackSpace = callbackMap[eventName];

        // Verify that there is an event space to unbind
        if (callbackSpace) {
            // Only unbind if there's an event bound with eventName and a callback with the specified callback
            if (callbackSpace[callback]) {
                $(that).unbind(makeEventName(eventName), callbackSpace[callback]);

                // Remove the callback from the callback map
                delete callbackSpace[callback];

                // Check if there are any members left on the event, if not we need to destroy it.
                if (!hasMembers(callbackSpace)) {
                    delete callbackMap[eventName];
                }
            } else if (!callback) { // Check if we're removing the whole event and we didn't error because of an invalid callback
                $(that).unbind(makeEventName(eventName));

                delete callbackMap[eventName];
            }
        }

        return that;
    },
```

that "event:callback" pair is removed from `callbackMap` on first call of the `off` function and unbound from hub (once). But on next call, the "event:callback" pair is not there anymore, so all other events are still bound to hub.

One solution could be to remove all callbacks from the event, by just calling `off` function with only `myEventName`, and not specifying the callback. But I'm not sure, if this is applicable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Calling .off() with only the event name is not applicable because all other callbacks really need to stay registered. I guess i have to find a workaround myself. Maybe call .on() once per event in a seperate service which broadcasts the data to the subscribed controllers. Then i can let my controllers subscribe/unsubscribe on that service instead of directly on the hub proxy. But it's very unfortunate unsubscribing specific callbacks is currently not supported, considering that you do can subscribe multiple callbacks.