# SignalR how to unbind an method listener

Tags: asp.net, signalr

```js
this.signalr = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl('/pipelinehub')
                    .build();
this.signalr.start();
this.signalr.on('somemethod', function () { ... });
```

So what I should do if I want to stop listening this method?

Answer (score 3):

According to [SignalR source code](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/f0a1b5bdb891601e730a7d0ea70cd85d7a09e527/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS/jquery.signalR.hubs.js) you can use `off`:

> Removes the callback invocation request from the server hub for the
>   given event name

```
 off: function (eventName, callback, callbackIdentity) {
    /// <summary>Removes the callback invocation request from the server hub for the given event name.</summary>
    /// <param name="eventName" type="String">The name of the hub event to unregister the callback for.</param>
    /// <param name="callback" type="Function">The callback to be removed.</param>
```

However you need to be careful when you use `On` and `Off` together. Take a look at:

[jQuery SignalR client .off() function only removes last registered callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336603/jquery-signalr-client-off-function-only-removes-last-registered-callback)